# How does eclipse get notified once a application launched by it, completed it's execution?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm new to eclipse plugin development & I'm trying to implement a debugger plugin (a different one from the default java debugger for some research purpose) for java apps. In the process I need to know when a java appliction launched through the launcher, completes it's execution to do some post execution tasks. How does eclipse get to know an application launched by it has finished it's execution ? or is it possible get notified of such scenario ?
But I'm prety much sure there should be a listner or something which get notified once an appliction launched by an eclipse laucher complets its execution.

Comment: Take a look at Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(hook);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For processes launched by Eclipse through the Run or Debug launch system you can use `org.eclipse.debug.core.IDebugEventSetListener` to get events include the process termination.
Set up with:

```
DebugPlugin.getDefault().addDebugEventListener(listener);
```